# Seemingly impossible square root solution

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]How is this equation possible? Maybe its the fact that I'm $20$ hours into a $40$ hour cram session, but this just doesn't make sense to me.

It's a standard Arc Length equation, $c(t)= (4-2t)\hat{\textbf{i}} +\ln(4t)\hat{\textbf{j}}+(5+t^2)\hat{\textbf{k}}$

I'm down to the point of finding the magnitude of $C'$ for the integral, but I'm stuck at this point

$(4+(\frac{1}{t^2})+4t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ My solution guide says this is equal to $\frac{2t^2 + 1}{t}$ but I just don't see it, please help.

Comment: $$4+ \frac{1}{t^2}+4t^2 = \frac{4t^2 + 1 + 4t^4}{t^2} = \frac{(2t^2)^2 + 2(2t^2)+1}{t^2} = \frac{(2t^2+1)^2}{t^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 4 + \frac{1}{t^2} + 4t^2 = \frac{4t^2 + 1 + 4t^4}{t^2} = \frac{(2t^2 + 1)^2}{t^2} = \left(\frac{2t^2 + 1}{t}\right)^2$$

So the square root is as given.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions given by George and Achille are very clear.
It's also beneficial to recognize your answer as a potential quadratic from the get go. Rearrange in order of descending powers to factor it more clearly:

$$\left(4t^2+4+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\left(\left(2t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Since $t>0$,

$$2t+\frac{1}{t}$$

$$\frac{2t^2 +1}{t}$$